# Laravel: [ErrorException] "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". during "composer install"

Tags: laravel, composer-php, php-7.2

When I run ...

```sh
composer install
```

... on a server with PHP and nginx installed.

I get the following exception:

> [ErrorException]
>     "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?

How can I fix this?

Comment: probably composer version is old, please try `composer self-update`, or install latest from composer site.

Answer (score 5):

This is a new warning introduced in PHP 7.3.

It means you are not allowed to have a `continue` statement inside of a `switch`, you should use `break` instead.

To fix this you most likely just have to update composer, this can be done simply by running `composer self-update`.

You can also just run php without warnings, this can be done by setting the ini config values as a start parameter.

```
php -d error_reporting=0 composer.phar
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your current PHP version if it's greater than 7.2, then execute follow below simple steps

*1. Disable the latest php version*

```
sudo a2dismod php7.3
```

*2. Restart the nginx service*

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

*3. If you are using Apache2 run as below*

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

*4. Set alternatives*

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

*5. Check the PHP version*

```
php -v
```

*6. Now, Install Composer as below*

```
composer install
```

Comment: Not solved yet, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Old composer uses `continue` statement in their code within the `switch` which is outdated and cannot be used anymore with latest version of php.

you need to update your composer

```sh
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=bin
```

for more details visit [composer download](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

Answer (score 0):

It was because of an outdated composer. After searching a lot finally the following works for me:

1. Uninstall the old composer.
2. Install a new updated composer.

You can download or install composer from this link: https://getcomposer.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

For me,
just go to this file

```
sudo nano /usr/share/php/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php
```

As a quick and dirty alternative, you can fix the error in that file. Just replace "continue" with "break"